# How to select specific QLabel in layout

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I have frame with QLabel in layer it and set style sheet.
when I set style for all QLabels style is applied correctly

```
QLabel{
  background: black;
}
```

but when i try to select specific QLabel style is not applied

```
mTitle->setObjectName("mTitle");
mTitle->setAccessibleName("mTitle");
```

and ive tried:

```
QLabel#mTitle
QLabel[objectName="mTitle"]
QLabel[accessibleName="mTitle"]
```

also via property

any idea what can cause this issue ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.  Are you sure you're setting the object name *before* setting the style sheet?

Comment: You should  indicate the parent widget first, e.g. `MainWidget QLabel#mTitle`

Comment: @G.M. you should not set stylesheet after each property change it should be done by polish/unpolish internally before showing each element. but just to be sure i did made sure that i set object name before style sheet. and i would like to provide reproducible example but that is not be possible since it is a part of huge project. what i am sure of when i set QLabel style globally it is styled correctly

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was rather badly worded.  The point I was trying to make was that setting the object name *after* setting the style sheet won't have the desired effect.  However, it sounds like you've already checked that.

Comment: Do you call `mTitle->setObjectName("mTitle");` in the widget's constructor or you change the `objectName` property value dynamically at runtime? In first case the order of `setObjectName` and `setStyleSheet` does not matter, in the second you must use `style()->unpolish(mTitle); style()->polish(mTitle);` for styles to work.

Comment: based on all you comments i played around and i think i find a "solution" to this issue @Alexey i use mTitle->setObjectName("mTitle"); in constructor of my widget where i put it into layout. what seems to work is when i create QLabel with default constructor QLabel() and then setObjectName() and then ... setParent(this); and this seems to apply styles correctly.